# Why doesn't this stopwatch start from zero?

Tags: python, tkinter

Whenever I run this script in tkinter GUI, it starts from 20:30:00, instead of 00:00:00.
I assume it has something to do with `count = 66600`. In the [source code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-stopwatch-using-python/) someone commented that `count = 10800` fix the same issue for them, but didn't do that for me.

```
counter = 66600
running = False
def counter_label(label):
    def count():
        if running:
            global counter
    
            # To manage the initial delay.
            if counter==66600:          
                display="Starting..."
            else:
                tt = datetime.fromtimestamp(counter)
                string = tt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                display=string
    
            label['text']=display 
            counter += 1
    
    # Triggering the start of the counter.
    count() 
    
#some code for rest of tkinter app.
```

By changing the count value the stopwatch starts from different times, and the lowest I found was 02:00:00. How can this be fixed? what does the count value represents?

Comment: Since you used `counter` in `datetime.fromtimestamp()`, then its value represents seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`.  Then `66600` means `1970-01-01 18:30:00 UTC`.  May be the time zone of your place has +2 hours offset, so you get `20:30:00`.

Comment: @acw1668 yes that was the issue, I selected a count value with an offset in seconds that's relative to a UTC/GMT -02:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about timezones.  Importing time would be better in this instance, because it offers a [naive object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#determining-if-an-object-is-aware-or-naive).

[image: counter label]

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import math
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import time

root = tk .Tk()
Width, Height = 300, 50

root .geometry( f'{Width}x{Height}' )
root .title( 'counter_label' )

lbl = tk .Label( root, width = 30, bg = '#ffffff' )
lbl .pack()

running = True
counter = 0
display = 'Starting...'

def count():
    if running:
        global counter, display

        seconds = counter % 60
        minutes = (counter // 60) %60
        hours = ( counter // (60 *60) ) % (60 *60)

        dt = time( second = seconds, minute = minutes, hour = hours )
        string = dt .isoformat( timespec = 'auto' )
        display = string

        lbl .config( text = display )
        counter += 1
    root .after( 1000, count )  ##  loop counter.  set @ 1 to see time fly

count()  ##  start counter
root .mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by determining the datetime corresponding to a timestamp value of `0`. Unfortunately to keep `datetime.fromtimestamp()` from adjusting it to your local time, you must supply a instance of a concrete `tzinfo` when calling it — so that's what the code below does.

Since you didn't provide a runnable MRE (Minimal Reproducible Example), I modified your code so it can be called without using `tkinter` — which I sure you can easily undo.

```
import datetime

UTC = datetime.timezone.utc
startdate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0, tz=UTC)
counter = datetime.datetime.timestamp(startdate)
running = True

def counter_label(label):
    def count():
        if running:
            global counter

            # To manage the initial delay.
            if counter == 0:
                display = "Starting..."
            else:
                tt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(counter, tz=UTC)
                string = tt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                display = string

#            label['text']=display
            print(display)
            counter += 1

    # Triggering the start of the counter.
    count()

for _ in range(10):
    counter_label(None)
```

Output:

```
Starting...
00:00:01
00:00:02
00:00:03
00:00:04
00:00:05
00:00:06
00:00:07
00:00:08
00:00:09
```

Comment: Can use `tz=datetime.timezone.utc` in `datetime.fromtimestamp()`.

Comment: @acw1668: *Very* good point—how embarrassing—I keep forgetting that was added to `datetime` a while back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by setting `count = -7200`, a negative value that fixes the offset of my [timezone](https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones) as commented on my question. A better way would be to hard code it, to keep datetime.fromtimestamp() from adjusting to the local time, as answered.